# Using Fancybox's Current image as document title

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events, fancybox-2

I currently have a web site I am building, with an image gallery on the posts. My question here is:

How do I take the current image's title attribute, and make it the document title.

Explained:

When image one, with a title of "Beautiful, isn't it?" is opened in the gallery, the document title is "Beautiful, isn't it?". Then, when image two, with the title of "Man! That car crash is horrible!" is in the gallery, the document title is "Man! That car crash is horrible!". This is a gallery, so images can be advanced within the FancyBox, and on change to the new image, the document title changes to the new image. When FancyBox is closed, document title returns to before (which could be defined in a variable at the beginning of the document, if necessary).

Comment: Try something like http://jsfiddle.net/ZJcD9/ (because of the iframe in fiddle the title will not change... but try it locally)

Comment: @R.S add `show/light/` to the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ZJcD9/show/light/) to see it as an independent page ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.title = 'This is easy!';
```

UPD:

have look at callbacks http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var origTitle = document.title

    $("#single_1").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          },
          afterShow: function() {
            document.title = $(this).attr('title');
          },
          afterClose: function () {
             document.title = origTitle;
          }
      });
});
```

full code on http://jsbin.com/olufus/1

Comment: +1 : you could also do `document.title = this.title;` (in the `afterShow` callback) where `this.title` is actually the fancybox selector's `title` ... **[jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jRsjK/1466/show/light/)**

Comment: JFK, You sir are awesome! Thanks. This is exactly what I needed, and I will most certainly use it!

Answer (score 0):

Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/ZJcD9/show/

Code http://jsfiddle.net/ZJcD9

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  title = document.title;

  $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            document.title = this.title;
        },
        beforeClose: function() {
            document.title = title;
        }
    });
})
```